# Concatenating two 1d numpy to create a Cartesian product of 2d numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a Cartesian product of two numpy so that the first numpy will be the rows and the second will be the columns.
For example get these two numpys:

```
a = np.array([0,0])
b = np.array([0,1,2,3])
```

The expected result should be 2d numpy like this:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 0 2]
 [0 0 3]]
```

The following code **does not** produce the requested result:

```
a = np.array([0,0])
b = np.array([0,1,2,3])

_new_ = []
for idx in range(len(a)):
    for i in a:
        newArr = np.append(a[idx], b)
        _new_.append(newArr)

print(np.stack(_new_))
```

What needs to be changed to produce the desired result?

Comment: I don't get the logic.  `a` has 2 elements, but the result has 3 columns.  If appending lists, I'd suggest sticking with lists, and don't try to use `np.append` (that's a nasty function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`np.tile`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) with [**`np.column_stack`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)

```
np.column_stack([np.tile(a, (len(b), 1)), b])

array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 3]])
```

If you have a `a` as 2D array

```
a = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1]])
b = np.array([0,1,2,3])

np.c_[np.tile(a, (len(b), 1)), np.repeat(b, len(a), axis=0)]

array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [1, 1, 3]])
```